# Conflict with Nvidia proprietary drivers + TeamSpeak 3

Tags: graphics, steam, nvidia-prime

I'm experiencing some very weird problemas. I'm running Ubuntu 16.10. Installed it fresh about a week ago. I updated my graphics card driver to Nvidia 367.57 and installed TeamSpeak 3.

The problem is the following: I start Steam, start running Rocket League or Dota 2 and everything works fine. I start up TeamSpeak and everything keeps working fine. Once I connect to a server in TeamSpeak I start experiencing a lot of graphic lag or something similar. Steam doesn't register it as fps drop because it keeps telling me I have about 50-60fps, but it is VERY obvious that there is something wrong. Even my mouse starts lagging both in-game and outside; doesn't matter what application I'm using.

I have tried both 32 and 64 bit TeamSpeak 3 apps; I even tried installing it via Wine. Nothing has seemed to work.

The mind-boggling thing (to me at least) is that it's not TeamSpeak itself or the Drivers themselves that cause the problem because it only shows when I'm connected to a TS server.

I have tried using the Nouveau drivers but they don't work very well so I can't tell if it has the same problem or if I really just have a fps drop because of the drivers. While using Prime Drivers I switched to the Intel card and the problem seems to go away, but now the GPU is not good enough to render the games.

I also tried selecting Pulse or ALSA on TeamSpeak, but no change.

Right now I'm not even sure what I should be looking for so any help and/or advice is more than welcome!

This are my system specs as shown by HardInfo:

[image]

Comment: I'm curious whether this is specific to TeamSpeak or whether it happens with other voice chat software too. Could you please try with [Mumble](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mumble/) (on a random server) instead just to rule that out?

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. I have tried Mumble too and there is no problem with Mumble, just TeamSpeak. I also tried Discord, but couldn't make it work. However there didn't seem to be any issues at all.

Comment: I changed the driver back to 340 and it did work well. However I did experience some FPS loss.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thank you for suggesting to post the answer myself. This is my first Q and A so I hope I did things right =] And also thank you for your help =]

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple enough: roll back the Nvidia drivers back to version 340.

Running Linux Mint 18 this is done simply by going to Driver Manager and selecting the Driver "nvidia-340" and rebooting.

I have not yet tested the latest "nvidia-378" to check if the problem persists. I did check the drivers "nvidia-367", "nvidia-370" and "nvidia-375" and I had the same problem. As stated, solution was to roll back drivers.